# Stanford NER: How do I create a new training set that I can use and test out?

Tags: stanford-nlp, training-data

From my understanding, to create a training file, you put your words in a text file. Then after each word, add a space or tab along with the tag (such as PERS, LOC, etc...)

I also copied text from a sample properties file into a word pad. How do I get these into a gz file that I can input into the classifier and use?

Please guide me though. I'm a newbie and am fairly inept with technology.

Answer (score 2):

Your training file (say `training-data.tsv`) should look like this:

```
I   O
drove   O
to  O
Vancouver   LOCATION
BC  LOCATION
yesterday   O
```

where `O` means "Outside", as in not a named entity.

where the space between the columns is a `tab`.

You don't put them in a `ser.gz` file. The ser.gz file is the classifier model that is *created* by the training process.

To train the classifier run:

```
java -cp ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop my-classifier.properties
```

where `my-classifier.properties` would look like this:

```
trainFile = training-data.tsv
serializeTo = my-classification-model.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you take a look at the NLTK documentation to learn more about training a parser http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/tag.html
. Now, it seems that you want to train the CRFClassifier (not the parser!); for that you may want to check this FAQ http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a